# Accessing homemade package from folder inside package, python

Tags: python, module, directory, package

I've been working on two packages for a few months as an intern, and I'm wrapping it up to deliver it to the next intern to continue working on it.
I'm having problems with accessing the packages from inside a combined folder. My folder structure looks like this:

```
> final_packages
__init__.py

    > stream_converter
        __init__.py
        matconverter.py
        matloader.py
    
    > stream_plotter
        __init__.py
        bits_params_manager.py
        params_manager.py
        plotter.py
        folder_plots.py
    
    > examples
        example4.py
```

The `__init__.py` files in `stream_converter` and `stream_plotter` just imports all the modules present in each respective folder. The `__init__.py` file in `Final_packages` is empty.

I can use the packages from a file which is in the same folder as `Final_packages` when I include the directory of `Final_packages` to `sys.path`. However, if the file is included in the `Examples` folder, I get the following error:

```
>> import stream_converter
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-2fa4258586e7>", line 1, in <module>
    import stream_converter

  File "C:\Users\kalse\OneDrive - Vestas Wind Systems A S\Personal Documents\Work_with_MORIK\Streaming_w_python\python3\Final_packages\stream_converter\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matconverter

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matconverter'
```

Somehow it seems that the python can't see the modules that are in the same folder as the `__init__.py`, even though it actually enters `__init__.py`. I would not expect it to be good practice t define a path inside these `__init__.py` files, so clearly I'm missing something - Can somebody help me here?

Best regards

Comment: `from final_packages import stream_converter`

Comment: In short, without setting up your project as a proper package, when `final_packages/__init__.py` gets to the statement `import stream_converter`, which will be able to find `final_packages/stream_converter/__init__.py` as `stream_converter` exists inside `final_packages`.  However when that second `__init__.py` tries to execute `import matconverter` it will not be able to find `matconverter.py` as it isn't inside `final_packages`.  My recommendation is to go through an [overview of packaging for Python](https://packaging.python.org/overview/) this should be turned into a proper Python package.